# How can I convert from a .txt file to a .xlsx?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert a little over 200 .txt files into .xlsx files. This is the code I'm using:

```
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim obj_folder As Object
Dim file As Object
Dim path As String
Dim destination As String
Dim file_name As String

path = "C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\Attributes Files\"
destination = "C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\Attributes xlx\"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
Set obj_folder = FSO.GetFolder(path)

For Each file In obj_folder.Files
    file_name = Left(file.Name, (InStrRev(file.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
    Call Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:=file, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True)
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=destination & file_name & ".xlsx"
    wb.Close savechanges:=False
Next file
```

When the code is finished running and I go to open the .xlsx workbook, I receive an error that states Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

I'm not sure what to do here as I know this works when I manually change one .txt file workbook to a .xlsx file type. I even recorded the macro and it more or less matches up with my code that I have here. (on one attempt I even copied down the recorded macro exactly and it still wouldn't let me open the .xlsx file after it finished.) Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You never cite what file format you save in. You want to use xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51

It looks like you pass the object file to the Filename paramter of open. I would use `file.Name` just like you do when you are building the output name.

Using a With block will gracefully handle the workbook object for you.
FSO.GetBaseName will remove the extension of the filename for you.

```
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")

Dim path As String
path = "C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\Attributes Files\"
Dim destination As String
destination = "C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\Attributes xlx\"

Dim file As Object
For Each file In FSO.GetFolder(path).Files
    Dim file_name As String
    file_name = FSO.GetBaseName(file.Name)
    With Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:=file.Name, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True)
        .SaveAs Filename:=destination & file_name & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51 
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With
Next file
```